# La columna 'fecha_Act_Formato' no pertenece a la Tabla

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, aspx

Tengo mi código el cual necesito mandar llamar una fecha, el problema es que me dice que el campo 'fecha_Act_formato' me dice que no pertenece a la tabla, pero ya lo tengo declarado, Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio .NET 2019 y con SQL Server, Tengo días con ese error, y además de que no solo me manda error en ese dato, pero resolviendo ese primer error puedo resolver los demás ya que me da el mismo error en diferentes datos. Les agradeceria mucho y alguien pudiera apoyarme.

Este es el codigo en Visual .NET

```
´if (Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["fecha_Act_Formato"]) == "")  //En esta línea me manda el error
            {
                lblRealizacion.Text = "SIN APLICACIÓN" + "<br /><br />";
                resultcumplimiento = resultcumplimiento + 0;
                lblCumFormatoADD.Text = "-";
            }
            else
            {
                lblRealizacion.Text = "FECHA DE REALIZACIÓN" + "<br />" + 
Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["fecha_Act_Formato"]).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
                resultcumplimiento = resultcumplimiento + 25;
                lblCumFormatoADD.Text = "CUMPLIMIENTO 25";
            }´
```

y Este es el Query, bajo SQL

```
*string sql =  @"SELECT DISTINCT sap.empresaSAP 
                            ,cge.NomRegion_Nueva 
                            ,sap.sucursalSAP 
                            ,CAST(sap.empleado as int) 
                            ,sap.paterno 
                            ,sap.materno 
                            ,sap.nombre 
                            ,sap.puesto 
                            ,sap.ingreso 
                            ,sap.SaludF
                            ,rie.riesgo
                            ,CONVERT(nvarchar(10), rie.fecha, 103)
                            ,pdi.Resultado_Aniversario
                            ,CONVERT(nvarchar(10), pdi.FechaCarga_Archivo, 103)
                            ,CONVERT(nvarchar(10), cemp.fecha_Act_Formato, 103)
                            ,cn.grave
                            ,CONVERT(nvarchar(10), cemp.fecha_Visita, 103)
                        FROM info_general.dbo.Carga_SAP sap
                        JOIN info_general.dbo.cat_gen_empresas cge on cge.idSucursal_SAP = 
sap.id_suc_SAP
                        JOIN Medicos.dbo.RegistroFRIEG rie ON CAST(rie.empleado as int) = 
CAST(sap.empleado as int)
                        JOIN prueba_integridad.dbo.Concentrado_PDI pdi ON CAST(pdi.Num_Empleado as 
int) = CAST(sap.empleado as int)
                        JOIN CIE.dbo.Empleados cemp ON 
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cemp.[Empleado],'/',''),':',''),' ', ''),'H', 
''),'O', ''),'R', '')  as int) = cast(sap.empleado as int)
                        JOIN CIE.dbo.Check_Novedades cn ON CAST(cn.empleado as int) = 
CAST(sap.empleado as int)
                        WHERE sap.baja is null
                        AND YEAR(rie.fecha) = YEAR(GETDATE())
                        ORDER BY --cge.NomSociedad_Padre, cge.NomRegion_Nueva, cge.NomSucursalC, 
                            cast(sap.empleado as int)"
                        ;*
```

y Este es el error que me manda

```
 System.ArgumentException: La columna 'fecha_Act_Formato' no pertenece a la tabla . en 
 System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName) en System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String 
 columnName) en InfoEmpleado.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) en 
 c:\sitios\SintesisCumplimiento\SintesisCumplimiento\InfoEmpleado.aspx.cs:línea 51
```

Comment: Cambia la query sql y ponle un alias a la columna. Al hacer un convert.... en tú código no sabe que es esa columna. Tienes que dejarlo tal que: ,CONVERT(nvarchar(10), cemp.fecha_Act_Formato, 103) As fecha_Act_Formato

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo mucho tu comentario Muchas gracias